# What is the difference between AWS::Serverless::Api and AWS::Serverless::HttpApi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

What is the difference between AWS::Serverless::Api and AWS::Serverless::HttpApi?

From what I can understand AWS::Serverless::HttpApi seems to configure the HTTP API which can also be configured with AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api, is this correct?

What does AWS::Serverless::Api configure, is it the old RestAPI which you also can configure through AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `AWS::Serverless::Api` configures **REST API**. `AWS::Serverless::Api` is a higher level resource then `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`.

For example with just single `AWS::Serverless::Api` you can define your paths (`/test`) and their methods (`GET`). The same using `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` is not possible. You have to separately construct `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource` and `AWS::ApiGateway::Method`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I assume the relationship between AWS::Serverless::HttpApi and AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api is the same?

Comment: @eternitysharp Yes. `AWS::Serverless` provides higher level resources then regular CloudFormation.

Answer (score 2):

AWS::Serverless::Api provides a traditional **RESTful** API endpoint, while AWS::Serverless::HttpApi provides a simpler and more lightweight **HTTP API** endpoint with support for WebSocket APIs.

**The main differences between AWS::Serverless::Api and AWS::Serverless::HttpApi are:**

1. **Configuration Model:** AWS::Serverless::Api has a more complex
   configuration model, where you define API resources and methods.
   AWS::Serverless::HttpApi has a simpler configuration model, where
   you define HTTP routes and methods.
2. **Function Integrations:**
   AWS::Serverless::Api supports integrations with AWS Lambda functions
   and other AWS services. AWS::Serverless::HttpApi supports
   integrations with AWS Lambda functions or other AWS services only.
3. **WebSocket APIs:** AWS::Serverless::HttpApi supports WebSocket APIs,
   which allows you to build real-time applications.
   AWS::Serverless::Api does not support WebSocket APIs.

Comment: how to make AWS::Serverless::HttpApi support WebSocket API? From the documentation, it doesn't seem to mention WebSocket